# How to ssh through a link

Tags: ssh, ngrok

So I was trying to connect to connect to my PC which is not on the same network as I am , So I do a quick research and installed an app called NGROK it basically provided me with a link which points to the computer port 22 on which I want to ssh , but I don't know the correct way to ssh through a link , nor am able to find a good article or documentation can anyone help me with this ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once an ngrok `tcp` tunnel is up and running you'll get an address like `0.tcp.ngrok.io:12345` and you can just use that hostname and port from an ssh client, for instance:

`ssh <user>@0.tcp.ngrok.io -p 12345`